# PHP include file in dynamic url

Tags: php

```
<?php include("data/url-last-path.php"); ?>
```

I am new to Php. Browser given last path should be displayed dynamic as mentioned in the above link. How to accomplish this?

Comment: The question is not clear enough to answer, please elaborate some more

Comment: actually my need is: 
I want in a single Php design template, bring multiple pages within that template from various data file present in the same domain.

Comment: I suppose you are looking for a [http redirect](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php), or you need to load those contents dynamically to the current page?

Comment: not http redirect. I need dynamic content loading based upon the last url path

Answer (score 1):

If you want to preserve data through pages(files) you should use super global variables like $_SESSION

http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php

Or in order to get information of paths or locations use $_SERVER

http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

> $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] Contains the address of the page (if any) which referred the user agent to the current page. This is set by the user agent. Not all user agents will set this, and some provide the ability to modify HTTP_REFERER as a feature. In short, it cannot really be trusted.

Answer (score 1):

Pass that value to another page .
So many mechanisms were there. Its up to you to decide.
Since i am not sure about what are you going to do. Let me give you some possibilities for sending data over pages.

1. POST (to next page)
2. GET (to next page)
3. COOKIE ( site level)
4. SESSION ( site level)

Passing value to a same page.

Example **page1.php**:

```
<form method="post" action="page1.php">
 <input type="text" name="lastpath">
  <input type="submit" >
</form>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['lastpath']))
 {
  require_once("data/".$_POST['lastpath']); 
 }
?>
```

Use require_once as Mr @humphrey said.

Comment: actually my need is: 
I want in a single Php design template, bring multiple pages within that single template from various data file present in the same domain.

Answer (score 1):

This is really simple. First, create an index.php file and place the following code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>One Page Template</title>
</head>
<body>

<p><a href="?page=">index</a> <a href="?page=page1">Page 1</a> <a href="?page=page2">Page 2</a></p>

<?php

$pageView   = 'index';

if(isset($_REQUEST['page']) && $_REQUEST['page'] != null){

    $pageView   = $_REQUEST['page'];

    include_once 'data/'.$pageView.'.php';

}else{

    include_once 'data/'.$pageView.'.php';
}
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Next, create a folder named "data" and create inside 3 files:

index.php, page1.php, page2.php

Place the following code on correspond file:

index.php:

```
<p>This is index <strong>Welcome!</strong></p>
```

page1.php:

```
<p>This is page 1</p>
```

page2.php:

```
<p>This is page 2</p>
```

Really simple!

Answer (score 0):

@vengets Answered your question but I also detected that you might get errors in future .
I suggest that you also  use this require_once because also in future when you will try to include a lot of files you will also get problems so this will solve them . this does not primarily answer your question but saves you from future errors

```
<?php require_once('data/url-last-path.php'); ?>
```